# How do I split data into multiple sheets where there are, e.g., 3 header rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning VBA, I have this code that I found online which has been great for splitting my data sheets. The problem is, I now have a new program I'm splitting for which has three header rows that have to be on each sheet.

Thanks!

```
Sub SplitDataNrows()

Dim N As Long, H As Long, rw As Long, lr As Long, Titles As Boolean

If MsgBox("Split the activesheet into smaller sheets?", vbYesNo, _
            "Confirm") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
N = Application.InputBox("How many rows per sheet?", "N-Rows", 50, Type:=1)
    If N = 0 Then Exit Sub
If MsgBox("Include the title row1 on each new sheet?", vbYesNo, _
            "Titles?") = vbYes Then Titles = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For rw = 1 + ---Titles To lr Step N
        Sheets.Add
        If Titles Then
            .Rows(1).Copy Range("A1")
            .Range("A" & rw).Resize(N).EntireRow.Copy Range("A2")
        Else
            .Range("A" & rw).Resize(N).EntireRow.Copy Range("A1")
        End If
        Columns.AutoFit
    Next rw

    .Activate
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

How can I amend this so that it asks me how many header rows there are and then put that number of rows on each new sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change `Titles` to a `Long` datatype and make use of `InputBox` again to allow a user to enter a number.

```
Sub SplitDataNrows()

Dim N As Long, H As Long, rw As Long, lr As Long, Titles As Long

If MsgBox("Split the activesheet into smaller sheets?", vbYesNo, _
            "Confirm") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
N = Application.InputBox("How many rows per sheet?", "N-Rows", 50, Type:=1)
    If N = 0 Then Exit Sub
Titles = InputBox("How many title rows?", "Title Rows",1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For rw = 1 + Titles To lr Step N
        Sheets.Add
        If Titles > 0 Then
            .Range("A1:A" & Titles).EntireRow.Copy Range("A1")
            .Range("A" & rw).Resize(N).EntireRow.Copy Range("A" & 1 + Titles)
        Else
            .Range("A" & rw).Resize(N).EntireRow.Copy Range("A1")
        End If
        Columns.AutoFit
    Next rw

    .Activate
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You might also consider adding an error handler to account for non-numeric entries from the user.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!

It's only for my own purposes, so I'm not too concerned about the error-handling, but I'll pop it in just in case I ever share it out!

Comment: Happy to have been helpful!